# How to ensure a kdb partitioned table data is not duplicated?

Tags: kdb

I created a partitioned db that gets data from daily stored files. It works fine but I'm worried that kdb could add duplicate rows if I run the partition script twice with the same day files.

Should I use 'key' to check for the existence of partitioned tables or there is a simpler way to insure kdb will not duplicate the stored data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your issue is that 1) you're afraid you'll load the same file more than once, or 2) multiple files may contain the same data, so you don't want subsequent loads to create duplicates.

For 1), if the daily stored files that you use to create the DB are not updated to and have unique names, you could possibly track which files have already been loaded and skip these on subsequent runs.

2) Even though you cannot physically key the table, you probably have certain "key" columns, e.g. sym, date, time, side etc. You can check if the "key" values of the chunk you are currently loading already appear in the date partition. If they do, drop those records, while keeping the others.

Comment: It's 1). Is there a kdb native way to track the uploaded files or I would have to persist some custom indicator on disk? I was looking for a kdb permission setting to block any write after creation. That would be the safest solution. Duplicating rows by accident would result in a disaster for the data analysis I'm performing and the extra rows would not be immediately detectable.

Comment: You would have to persist this info yourself. You could include a column which indicates the file which provided each record in the table. 

Does each file contain a separate days data, or does are there multiple files per date, or dates per file?

Comment: There are multiple files for each date. If I store the same file twice I would skew the data and produce wrong results. What if I play with the linux file permissions on the partition directory after creation?

Comment: I think that's possibly over complicating things. You could still use my 2nd suggestiong above. If a key already exists, ignore that record. You could also take account of the possibility of duplicate records in your analysis by using fby. (i=(last;i)fby([]$KEY1;$KEY2...). Realistically this is quite a user specific issue, without being familiar with your data and what you're trying to do with it, it's kindof difficult to provide complete solution.

Comment: Basically. You know what keys are in the incomming file, it those keys already exist in a partition, then you ignore the record. It's not a very elegant solution, and it will increase the load time. But as I said, it's difficult to come up with a complete solution without knowing the full extent of what you're trying to do. If there's a risk of you loading a file multiple times, then your analytics should be more forgiving in the case where there are duplicates.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm surprised there is no read/write control. Accidental writes can impact analytics in a significant way. Basic write security could be embedded in kdb, just like regular file permissions (O_CREAT).